# Is any way to set success_url from urlconf parameter?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

in urls.py:

```
url(r'^add/from?(?P<link>[a-zA-Z0-9/]+)$', PostAdd.as_view(), name='post_add'),
```

in views.py:

```
class PostAdd(CreateView):

model = Post
form_class = PostForm
template_name = 'post_add.html'
success_url = ????

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(PostAdd, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['from'] = self.kwargs['link']
    return context
```

I can pass *link* to the template, but I need to set *success_url=link*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should override the [`get_success_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) method on the view, rather than using the success_url attribute.

```
class PostAdd(CreateView):

    def get_success_url(self):
        # Grab 'link' here and return it:
        return self.kwargs['link']
```